# Stream reference error

Tags: c#

Compiler Error Message:   'Stream' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.IO.Stream' and 'WebReference.Stream'

Any thoughts?

I have web method accepting `System.IO.Stream` stream as an input parameter & internally i assing `stream=new MemoryStream(bytes[]);`

Comment: fully qualify the use of 'Stream' in your non-compiling code

Answer (score 0):

You probably have both `System.IO` and `WebReference` in your `using` declarations of the file, so the compiler doesn't know which one you want to use.

You can fully qualify its use, remove an unused reference, or alias one of them in the using declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a class called `Stream` in multiple namespaces.

Assuming both of your original using directives are required, you can resolve this in two ways:

1. Use the fully qualified name:

   `System.IO.Stream stream = new MemoryStream();`
2. Add a [alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28VS.71%29.aspx) at the top:

   using `Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream;`

Answer (score 0):

at the top of the code file your using both `System.IO` and `WebReference`.

So when you use `Stream` the compiler doesn't know what you are referring.

Just use the fully qualified name:

```
System.IO.Stream stream=new MemoryStream(bytes[]);
```

Comment: This is the webservice method i have

LoadImageFromDB(int ID, ref Stream streamReturnVal)

I have this on the top of the section using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream;

Whenever i consume this method(update web reference) from a web application, i get this error

'Stream' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.IO.Stream' and 'WebReference.Stream'

Any thoughts?